# floating-point stack operation

Tags: floating-point, stack

I have to read a program which synthesizes a benchmark. I am unfamiliar with floating point stack. The code is as follows. The following code is in a for statement.I don't write the for statement, because it is extremely large. Each loop seems to modify the FP stack and each loop has to restore the FP stack before the next loop begins.

```
//since the synthetic will be run (probably) multiple times, the FP stack needs to be clear

           if(floatStackSize > 6)
           {
                 initializeFPStack();
                 floatStackSize = 0;
           }
           else
           {
                 while(floatStackSize > 0)
                 {
                    adjustFPStack(floatStackSize);
                    floatStackSize = floatStackSize - 1;
                 }
           }
```

initializeFPStack and adjustFPStack function code are as follows.

```
//initializeFPStack
    void initializeFPStack(void) //needed
    {
        string fileName = outputFileName;

        ofstream outputFile(fileName.c_str(), ios::app);        //open a file for writing (append the current contents)

        if(!outputFile)  //check to be sure file is open
            cout << "Error opening file.";

        outputFile << "   __asm__ __volatile__ (\"fninit " << "\");\n";

        outputFile.close();
    }

//adjustFPStack
void adjustFPStack(size_t floatStackSizE) //needed
{
    string fileName = outputFileName;

    ofstream outputFile(fileName.c_str(), ios::app);        //open a file for writing (append the current contents)

    if(!outputFile)  //check to be sure file is open
        cout << "Error opening file.";

    outputFile << "\n   __asm__ __volatile__ (\"fcomp " << "%st" << "\");\n";

    outputFile.close();
}
```

Can somebody give me a tutorial or link that teaches the floating point stack? Additionally, I want to know what the above code does and why it has to do the above actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "floating point stack" is a feature of x86 processors. It contains eight floating point registers, plus a stack pointer, and the instructions that operate on these registers treat them as a stack. These registers and instructions are collectively called x87. You can find the full details in the *Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual*. Chapter 8 of [Volume 1](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf) describes the architecture and general principles. [Volume 2](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) describes the effects of every instruction.

Modern processors contain additional floating point registers and different instructions that operate on these other registers. These registers and instructions are collectively called SSE. They are generally more efficient than x87.